# How to find how many of the variables in table 1 are found in table 2?

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP I select from mySQL table `one` some rows containing the column `hash` for a specific day. All these rows are unique.
Also, from table `two` I do the same thing, I get the column `hash` for a specific day, again uniques.

Using PHP, how can I know how many `hash` from table `one` are found on table `two`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$equals = 0;
    foreach($firstArrayWithHash as $item1){
       foreach($secondArrayWithHash as $item2){
          if($item1 == $item2){
             $equals++;
          }
       }
     }
```